# Why does my game crash in PYGAME every time I try to shoot

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I am making a 2 player fighting game and whenever I try and press "v" the, the key to shoot my game seems to crash and not work. I am new to pygame and I am learning as I go. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#Sets up 8 bit colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
lightblue = (180,235,255)
grassgreen =(20,200,50)

#Sets up pygame window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Fighter')



#Variables
gameExit = False
x = 0
y = 0
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
isShooting = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x_change, y_change, x, y):
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        self.x= 50
        self.y= 480

    def Left(self, x_change):
        self.x_change = -5
    def Right(self, x_change):
        self.x_change =5
    def Jump(self, y_change):
        if (self.y == 480):
            self.y_change = -70
            return
p1 = Player(x_change, y_change, x, y)

class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, Player, x_change):
        self.x = p1.x
        self.y = p1.y
        self.x_change = 0
    def Show(self, x_change, x , y, Player ):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black , [p1.x,p1.y,5,5])
        self.x_change = 10
b1 = Bullet(x, y, Player, x_change)

#Main Game Loop
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                p1.Left(x_change)
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                p1.Right(x_change)
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                p1.Jump(y_change)
            if event.key == pygame.K_v:
                b1.Show(x, y, x_change, Player)
                isShooting = True
        while isShooting:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [b1.x, b1.y , 5,5])
            if b1.x > 1000:
                pass
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                p1.x_change = 0

    if p1.x <= 0:
        p1.x = 0
    if p1.x >= 500:
        p1.x = 500

    if p1.y > 480:
        p1.y_change = 0
        p1.y = 480
    if p1.y < 480:
        p1.y_change = 5

    p1.x += p1.x_change
    p1.y += p1.y_change
    b1.x += b1.x_change
    gameDisplay.fill(lightblue)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, grassgreen, [1000,600,-1000,-100])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [p1.x,p1.y,20,20])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What debugging have you done before asking?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like once isShooting is set to True, the program gets stuck in the while loop (while isShooting:). It seems like you need a condition in the while loop to set isShooting back to False if a certain conditions is met, for example, if the v key is released.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `while` loop. `while isShooting` should be removed. The player should shoot at most one time per game loop - any more than that and they won't be able to see the effects of them firing. Plus, you create an infinite loop.

On another note, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't yet, check out the tour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks, I will try and fix this bug tomorrow (It is late in Worcester (UK)) but  thanks for your help